# PHP Session ID Duplication?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How unique is the php session id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id)

Can there be a duplicate PHP Session ID?

I have not had this problem, but i want to see if this could be a issue in the future.

Comment: Does memory corruption count as a reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but unlikely in most cases.

Comment: Are you sure that PHP would really do that?

Comment: That PHP assigns the same session number by design (albeit not always).

Comment: @hakre: huh? assigns where? session id is calculated on some "random" parameters

Comment: ""random"" seems to match it.

Answer (score 0):

If I were one of php's developers I would check wether the generated session id matches any of existing ones, and generate a new one until I get unique data. And if I saw this way, I'm sure of php developers did indeed