# How Symfony generates session ID?

Tags: symfony

I was wondering how Symfony generates session IDs? I was trying to find a snippet reponsible for it but I couldn't. Does it check for colission before returning ID or is it possible (probably nearly impossible but possible) to generate the same session ID for two users?

Comment: If you haven't played to much with the configuration, sessions use by default the native php ones: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session I guess this is then more a generic php question!

Answer (score 1):

You can search for classes which implements `SessionStorageInterface`.

By default native PHP session storage is used, therefore PHP's [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is responsible for generating IDs.

Edit: There is another discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id) about how unique is this native session id.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the default storage handler is named `NativeSessionStorage` in the namespace `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage`