# PHP: How to identify a running script instance in the log?

Tags: php

I use function **error_log()** in my PHP script. If several instances of the script run concurrently, all of them will write into the same log file, and their messages will intermingle. I need to tell their records one from another.

I would be able to do so, if I had a unique ID for each running script, say, **$script_id**, so I would output a log message **$message** like this:

```
error_log($script_id . ': ' . $message);
```

but can I retrieve such a unique ID anywhere?

**UPDATE 1:** Or is there a better way of logging for these circumstances?

**UPDATE 2:** It would be interesting to retrieve the process ID of the process in which the script runs.

Comment: You can just make a random ID. [Here's a google search for "PHP random string"](https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20random%20string). "Yes, but it isn't UNIQUE!!!". Sure, but the risk that duplicate random strings will occur at the same time is minimal. If you really wish, keep a DB table of ID's and when you create a unique ID verify that it isn't in the DB.

Comment: Why not just use Unix time?

Comment: with `session`, you can use the `session_id()`;

Comment: @JamesHunt 5 requests/script instances in a second would get the same ID which is not what he wants.

Comment: @h2ooooooo A random number may be good, if it is random enough.

Comment: @AlexK I've had success with 5 random A-Z0-9 characters before. They're easy to distinguish (numbers are not as much) and the risk of a concurrent collision is `1 / 52521875`. If you wish, you can simply use 6 characters and up that to `1 / 1838265625`.

Comment: Yes, @JamesHunt, the time is only in the one-second resolution.

Comment: why not append datetime now microtime to it..

Comment: you can create a random id from a big random number and with a microtime ctypted with md5. but why `session_id();` is not good for you?

Comment: @lolka_bolka, session_id() is good, if opening a session is not detrimental in any way. Please put your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: opening a session is not detrimental, but i read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id so i do not suggest you to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php function [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) :

```
$script_id = uniqid();
error_log($script_id . ': ' . $message);
```