# Creating Session ID from MD5 Hash

Tags: php, session, md5

Currently I have this:

```
$time = time();
$hash = md5($key . $time);
```

but how do I create a `$_SESSION['']` based on the the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see why this wont work.

```
$time = time();
$hash = md5($key . $time);
$_SESSION['time'] = $hash;
```

Then try echo it to test:

```
echo $_SESSION['time'];
```

or store in your own var

```
$mysession = $_SESSION['time'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it with:

```
 session_id($hash);
 session_start();
```

You can find the explanation in the manuals:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: You might consider using php's built-in session id generator; it's designed for security (difficulty to guess) by crypto folks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make session more secure against [session fixation attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), you can use [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) and re-create a new session_id after every *x* requests:

```
$_SESSION['last_time_generated']++;

if ($_SESSION['last_time_generated'] > 10) {
    $_SESSION['last_time_generated'] = 0;
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
```