# PHP Session_Start() intermittently failing on Permission denied

Tags: php, session

I wondered if anyone has come across this before or can think of ways to help me debug this further.

I have thousands of users all login and gain sessions perfectly fine, but every so often (maybe once a day) I get the following error:

> PHP Warning: session_start(): open(C:\Windows\Temp\sess_n6cbb6rtg8p9p11fohjdt6btd6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login.php on line 31

The folder has full write permissions as otherwise I would have thousands of these errors.

The only thing I can possibly think of is some sort of file-lock for that session that has gone wrong, but I cant think how.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Might be a lock, as you mentioned, when two users try to login at the same time?

Comment: Two things come to mind. 1. System manage to create duplicate sessions ID's. Take a look here to see if this might be to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138670/how-unique-is-the-php-session-id 2. The file is automatically cleaned up as the user try to access it.